# Aircrack-ng "successfuly" cracks a .cap file, but it outputs the wrong password

Tags: penetration-test

This is my first post and I hope this is in the right section.

I've been toying with attempting to crack my wpa password with aircrack-ng and airodump. I've successfully grabbed the 4-way handshake and run the .cap file through aircrack-ng. I know that my password is in the list, but for some reason when it "successfully" cracks the password it says the password is "1234567890", which is not correct.

I've seen a couple of posts floating around, but none of really addressed it. Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

looks like you've cracked the default WPS pin and not the WPA2 password.
however, that pin can be used to get the WPA2 password, so you're almost there.

The strange thing is that I wasn't aware aircrack-ng targeted WPS, so maybe your .cap file captured someone elses handshake? some funny business is definitely happening. Some more information about your setup would be handy.

Perhaps start the attack again, get a fresh handshake, and confirm the router password is applied properly, some routers require a restart to properly make changes.